# Insert timestamp in Mongodb from PHP with MongoDate, insert 2 hours less

Tags: php, mongodb

What could be the cause of that when I insert a Date in Mongo, the result is 2 hours less.
This is the parameter:

```
"Date"=>new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-05-18 18:51:00"))
```

And the result in Mongodb after insert is:
2015-05-18 **16:51:00**.000Z

I checked the hour in the server but is correct, 18:51 at the moment of the test.

The only way I found to set the correct value in mongodb is with hardcode adding 2 hours:

```
"Date"=>new MongoDate(strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 2*3600)))
```

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2015-05-18 16:51:00.000Z - it is UTC time and value is correct

Comment: Thanks, ok, It's the UTC, but if I want to save a simple Date at 18:51:00 when the UTC is 16:51:00, How should I do it? Because when I need to read the Date value the UTC it's not the correct Date.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Dolbik's comment I'll add that Mongo stores all dates in UTC and [here you'll find relevant documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date)